# c# Placeholder from input in web browser

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, placeholder

A little strange but it seems like there is nothing for "Placeholders" in the web browser in winforms c#.

In my test program i am trying to get specific input field from a website through it's "Placeholder" and set a value in the field. The name and class are always different and the only "footprint" is the placeholder.

For example in the html of some website, there is input field with this code: 
`<input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username">` The problem is to set a value in the field by finding the placeholder.

I'm taking the input elements with: 
`HtmlElementCollection htmlcol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");`
and searching the specific input with loop `htmlcol[i].GetAttribute("placeholder").Equals("Username").` It's just not working

Any idea or an example on how to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is it that you're asking?

Comment: he wants to get an element by finding a `placeholder` attribute with a specified value... His question is pretty clear

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough and it might be confusing. For example in the html of some website, there is input field with this code:
<input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username">

The problem is to set a value in the field by finding the placeholder.

Hope you'll understand me now :)

Comment: @BombaRuLz Ok, I reverted the -1 after your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing for 2 days i've found that there isn't anything in the innerHtml for the placeholder inside the input field (except name, id, class and similar) when accessing through webbrowser. I tried accessing like with `htmlcol[i].GetAttribute("placeholder").Equals("Username");` but for some reason it didn't worked.

What worked for me is **OuterHtml**, something like this:

```
HtmlElementCollection htmlcol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
for (int i = 0; i < htmlcol.Count;  i++)
     {
     if (htmlcol[i].OuterHtml.Contains("Username"))
        {
           htmlcol[i].SetAttribute("value", pUsername.Text);
        }
}
```

I hope that my answer will help somebody regarding this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First You need to Get That Container Element And then you can set Values for it's Values

Eg,

```
        HtmlElementCollection htmlcol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach(HtmlElement he in htmlcol){
        if(he.innerHtml.Contains("Username"))

        he.SetAttribute("value",yourstring);
        break;
        }
```

Comment: I'm already taking the input elements with:
`HtmlElementCollection htmlcol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");` and searching the specific input with loop `htmlcol[i].GetAttribute("placeholder").Equals("Username")`. It's just not working

Comment: Your code should work just like mine but the thing is, for unknown reasons there is null exception, it's like the placeholder doesn't exist in the web browser.

Cheers

Comment: okay, then check if the element is not null before if statement... like this if(he!=null){ if(he.innerHtml...}